# Throwing exception in WCF service operation, anything to look out?

Tags: wcf, exception

I am just learning WCF and wrote a Windows Service hosting a WCF service. Ever since I started it in service.msc in the remote server (physically remote, and very slow) I think I have already hit and fixed like a hundred errors here and there already. I am now finally stuck.

At this point, I have enabled tracing and message logging. The first and only function call looks like this:

```
[OperationContract]
public MyServiceResponse ConnectToAXDynamicsViaDotNET2BusinessConnectorWithSadFace()
{
    try
    {
        throw new NotImplemented();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
         return new MyServiceResponse(ex, ex.Message);
    }
}

[DataContract]
public class MyServiceResponse
{
     // ...
}
```

Upon calling the operation, the client just sits and waits until timeout. Checking the trace, it records my thrown exception. So it makes me wonder if WCF actually blocks there and ignore my catch clause.

I then tested with just a simple return value without throwing and it FINALLY works.

My question is, how then can I make the above scenario work, ie. catch the exception and return a sensible result back to client? Maybe it's just the tracing that blocks me, but I want to enable tracing during this whole debugging process otherwise it's really hard to work.

Thanks for your precious help!

**EDIT**: Sorry, I found this right after I posted this question. Happens all the time: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942778.aspx but I have yet to read it as I got to run off now. Not sure it it will solve my problem.

Comment: Neither tracing or the way your catching your exception should cause any sort of problem.  I'm guessing you have something else going on.  What happens if you don't throw an exception and just return a response?  Try that and invoke your service via the WCF Test Client.  Are you able to successfully call the service?

Comment: Thanks chris.house.00; as I mentioned in the OP, "I then tested with just a simple return value without throwing and it FINALLY works."

Comment: Big problem: you're eating the details of your exceptions. Use a specific `FaultException<T>` when you know what exactly happened, and define in `[FaultContract]`. Otherwise, just don't catch the exception, and let WCF handle it.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Sorry, I just edited the code. I attempted to pass the exception object together as well. I know this breaks the service model rule etc. this is just testing code. I am learning. Any case, I am now using FaultException. Still, thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Risk being downvoted, but just for documentation sake and general usefulness of having this question:

Through reading the FaultException handling articles, I *guess* the above behavior is due to Exception class not serializable. And the service silently disconnects itself without returning any error messages eventhough the "send (unknown) faults to client" is enabled. As for why it does so, I have no idea yet. Will update if I find out more.

I have since changed to throw new FaultException() instead of returning my own MyServiceResponses.

Comment: additionally, when the CustomData in FaultException<CustomData> has serialisation issues, such as no setter for DataMember, it also disconnects silently.